# I am getting some data using powershell command from python without having a cmd in windows! how can i assigned this output to a string variable?

Tags: python, string, powershell, text-files

I am getting some data using PowerShell command from python without having a cmd in windows by this command!

```
import os
windows_info = os.system('powershell.exe get-physicaldisk')
```

and it's successfully working. but this output gives an 'int' output! I tried to covert this into a string by using,

```
windows_infoEG = str(windows_info)
```

but when I tried to print this it won't print anything(but when I check its type its says 'str'). how can I turn this into a string in order to write the output into a text file!

this is my whole code.

```
 import os
    
    windows_info = os.system('powershell.exe get-physicaldisk')
    print(type(windows_info)) 
    
    windows_infoEG = str(windows_info)
    print(type(windows_infoEG)) 
    
    print(windows_infoEG)
    
    f = open("hardDriveInfo.txt", "w")
    f.write("Hard Drive Info" + windows_infoEG)
    f.close()
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` returns you the "exit code" of the process (usually 0 for success, non-zero for failure).  That's why you get an integer.  It does NOT return to you the standard output of the command.  For that, you need the `subprocess` module.

```
windows_info = subprocess.check_output(['powershell.exe','get-physicaldisk']).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I'd like to add a link to the documentation of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than that.  `os.system` serves a useful purpose.  One problem is that the word "results" is ambiguous.  `os.system` DOES return the "result" of the process, but if you want to hook the stdin and stdout, it isn't the right tool.